# Removing animations from shapes using python-pptx

Tags: python-pptx

I have a python application that generates powerpoint presentations and fills them with data based on a template presentation and the given data.

In some cases shapes get deleted if expected data isn't provided in a dataset.
For that I am using the following two lines of code from another thread (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66176495/18337451):

```
sp = shape._element
sp.getparent().remove(sp)
```

Some of those shapes that might get deleted also carry animations, which causes trouble now. Generated PowerPoint presentations, where a shape gets deleted that carries an animation, come out with the "repair"-notice. Repairing generally works fine, but the slides in question lose all their animations.

Unfortunately repairing and losing the animations isn't an option and I was wondering if there is a way to somehow access the animations of a slide and delete them when neccessary.

When browsing here I've learned that this is a natural case when a deleted shape is in a relationship with something else, in my case an animation. I haven't seen animations in `python-pptx` being discussed in detail here, which is why I decided to ask on here whether there is some way to access slide animations using `python-pptx`.

I could also increase my template presentation and remove the need for deleting shapes, but directly accessing animations and removing them on demand would be a quicker solution and also my preferred one if possible.

Comment: I think we'd need to figure out which parts (within the .pptx zip file) carry the animation information. Then we could figure out how to remove those. (I say "we" but it's not me as I have no real interest in animation yet.)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem, but found just as little solution. So I took a look at the PP OpenXML structure (https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/shp-movie.html lists some useful links about animations).

At least in my PP file, a group/shape/... looks like this, for example:

```
<p:nvSpPr>
    <p:cNvPr id="21" name="the name of the shape in pp - as can be seen in the annimations tab">
        <a:extLst>
            <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main"
                                id="{98BAD8BC-0BED-13E4-F6CA-8AF968326972}"/>
            </a:ext>
        </a:extLst>
    </p:cNvPr>
    <p:cNvSpPr/>
    <p:nvPr/>
</p:nvSpPr>
```

As you can see, it carries an `id` (`21` in this case). This is referenced again later in the OpenXML for the annimation with the parameter `spid`:

```
<p:spTgt spid="21"/>
```

At least in my case, it is always the fact that the entire/actual/"main" animation element is 7 levels higher than this `<p:spTgt spid="21"/>`.
Therefore you can get this "main" element and delete it afterwards as well. The animation disappears and at least for me no repair dialog is shown when I open the PP file edited this way.

So the code you are looking for should look something like this:

```
sp = shape._element
sp_id = sp.get("id")
animation_reference = sp.findall(f'.//*[@spid="{sp_id}"]')
animation_main_element = animation_reference.find("./../../../../../../..")
animation_main_element.getparent().remove(animation_main_element)
sp.getparent().remove(sp)
```